# Cannot call my custom razor page (HTTP 404)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC application from scratch with authentication by "storing user accounts in-app". I extended ASP Identity with my own custom `VerifyEmail.cshtml` razor page.

This looks quite good, doesn't it?

[image: Custom razor page inside Manage folder]

But I cannot request https://localhost:44345/Identity/Account/Manage/VerifyEmail, it got 404!

**What did I forget?**

Here's the `VerifyEmail.cshtml`:

```html
@model VerifyEmailModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Verify Email";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.VerifyEmail;
}
<h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
<partial name="_StatusMessage" for="StatusMessage" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
            </div>
            <button id="email-verification" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Send verification email</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how your `VerifyEmail` class please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@page` on your first line of `VerifyEmail.cshtml` :

```
@page
@model VerifyEmailModel
```

`@page` makes the file into an MVC action - which means that it handles requests directly, without going through a controller. `@page` must be the first Razor directive on a page. `@page` affects the behavior of other Razor constructs.